# Can Heaven be Precipitous?

Tags: bach, taz

[image]

And so it is told (Intro to L'Dofkei B'tshuva) that the Bach, by agreement, was required to supply daily 'meat' portions to his son-in-law the Taz. Here is my loose translation:

> One time the Bach fed lung as a meal to the Taz instead of meat. The Taz proceeded to summon the Bach to a rabbinical tribunal. And the Taz had grounds to do so - after all, lung is part of the intestines and is not fit to be called meat. The tribunal adjudicated the matter in favor of the Bach - lung = meat. The Chazon Ish explains that on the day that the Taz ate the lung he lacked his normal daily strength and studied torah for less minutes. A heavenly claim was thus lodged against the Bach for causing all of this. The Taz knew of this divine claim and wanted to expunge it. He therefore summoned the Bach to the tribunal in order to have the court arrive at the conclusion that the Bach was right - lung is meat - this would cancel the divine decree because heaven follows the decrees of earthy courts.

But if the Taz already knew the earthly outcome - lung = meat, why did heaven initially take another position?

The key must lie in the words ונימוקו עמו - and his basis/argument was with him (the Taz had grounds to bring this claim).

There must have been this prima facie assumption that lung was not meat ... this assumption caused the kitrug, was in error, the Taz knew it was in error, and thus he became the catalyst to have a correct ruling be issued to exonerate the Bach. But Shamayim's (erroneous) kitrug here seems precipitous and based on a general assumption which was one step behind the Taz ... strange.

Comment: I think I heard *peshat* that the question was *mistovev* around whether the Taz was classified as an *ani klapei shmaya*.

Comment: I heard the point was, there mightve been a taina on the bach, so going to court would for sure get rid of it.

Comment: You need to set the precedent, and this was the first occurrence with a nafka mina,so needed to be brought to court

Comment: You can OCR the image of the text so that the text is accessible to searches and potentially reach more people interested in the material you present. There are plenty of free sites online such as https://www.i2ocr.com/free-online-hebrew-ocr where this can be done.